# Error when sending data type Json using Post

Tags: c#, post

This is link Web Site : https://app.golike.net/login . I test by display the result to label3 (if it work) . Do i do wrong anything . Help me Thanks

```
private void testlogingo(string tkgo,string mkgo)
        {
            try
            {
                string webAddr = "https://dev.golike.net/api/login";

                var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
                httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
                httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    string json = "{\"username\": asdsadsa,\"password\": sadasda}";

                    streamWriter.Write(json);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
                var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    label13.Text = responseText;  
                }
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("dsfd");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you showing "dsfd" instead of the actual exception? Have you tried debugging the application to see the actual problem? You are not explaining what your actual problem is.

Comment: its just a fake username and password . I dont want to show my username password . Second . IF it work i should print like :` "status": 401,
    "success": false data": [],
    "error": [],
    "message": "T\u00ean \u0111\u0103ng nh\u1eadp ho\u1eb7c m\u1eadt kh\u1ea9u kh\u00f4ng t\u1ed3n t\u1ea1i trong h\u1ec7 th\u1ed1ng" . ` . Then i will know that the code work or not .